# Creating Function for Pandas that takes arguements (df, columnname) and calculates null percentgage

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning Python's Pandas library using kaggle's titanic tutorial. I am trying to create a function which will calculate the nulls in a column.

My attempt below appears to print the entire dataframe, instead of null values in the specified column:

```
def null_percentage_calculator(df,nullcolumn):
    df_column_null = df[nullcolumn].isnull().sum()
    df_column_null_percentage = np.ceil((df_column_null /testtotal)*100)
    print("{} percent of {} {} are NaN values".format(df_column_null_percentage,df,nullcolumn))

null_percentage_calculator(train,"Age")
```

My previous (and very first stack overflow question) was a similar problem, and it was explained to me that the `.index` method in pandas is undesirable and I should try and use other methods like `[ ]` and `.loc` to explicitly refer to the column.

So I have tried this:

```
df_column_null=[df[nullcolumn]].isnull().sum()
```

I have also tried

```
df_column_null=df[nullcolumn]df[nullcolumn].isnull().sum()
```

I am struggling to understand this aspect of Pandas. My non function method works fine:

```
Train_Age_Nulls = train["Age"].isnull().sum()
Train_Age_Nulls_percentage = (Train_Age_Nulls/traintotal)*100
Train_Age_Nulls_percentage_rounded = np.ceil(Train_Age_Nulls_percentage)
print("{} percent of Train's Age are NaN values".format(Train_Age_Nulls_percentage_rounded))
```

Could anyone let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Where is testtotal defined in your function?

Comment: This will print the entire dataframe: `print("{} percent of {} {} are NaN values".format(df_column_null_percentage,df,nullcolumn))`. You probably want: `print("{} percent of {} are NaN values".format(df_column_null_percentage, nullcolumn))` (i.e. remove `df` from the arguments to be printed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def null_percentage_calculator(df,nullcolumn):
    df_column_null = df[nullcolumn].isnull().sum()
    df_column_null_percentage = np.ceil((df_column_null /testtotal)*100)
    # what is testtotal?
    print("{} percent of {} {} are NaN values".format(df_column_null_percentage,df,nullcolumn))
```

I would do this with:

```
def null_percentage_calculator(df,nullcolumn):
    nulls = df[nullcolumn].isnull().sum()
    pct = float(nulls) / len(df[nullcolumn]) # need float because of python division
    # if you must you can * 100
    print "{} percent of column {} are null".format(pct*100, nullcolumn)
```

beware of python integer division where 63/180 = 0

if you want a float out, you have to put a float in.

Comment: Ah sorry I defined testtotal outside of the function : testtotal=(len(test.index))

Comment: Hi there, I got the following error message with your function : File "<ipython-input-25-e71177026a43>", line 5
    print "{} percent of column {} are null".format(pct*100, nullcolumn, len(df[nullcolumn]))
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Thank you for your help guys,  @IanS was right I was printing out df thinking it would only print out the name of the df not the entire thing!   this works now:  def null_percentage_calculator(df,nullcolumn):
    df_column_null = df[nullcolumn].isnull().sum()
    df_column_null_percentage = np.ceil((df_column_null /traintotal)*100)
    print("{} percent of {} are NaN values".format(df_column_null_percentage, nullcolumn))

null_percentage_calculator(train,"Age")

Comment: yeah, sorry about that, i don't know why I put the 3rd element in the `.format()` - I'm glad you worked it out.